# Share image from windows store app using share charm

Tags: c#, xaml, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

I want to share my canvas as image in my window store app I am using this code

```
if (DrawCanvas.Children.Count == 0)
            {
                MessageDialog dlg = new MessageDialog("Please add some content", "Warning");
                dlg.ShowAsync(); 
                return;
            }

            // Render to an image at the current system scale and retrieve pixel contents
            RenderTargetBitmap renderTargetBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap();
            await renderTargetBitmap.RenderAsync(DrawCanvas);
            var pixelBuffer = await renderTargetBitmap.GetPixelsAsync();

            var savePicker = new FileSavePicker();
            savePicker.DefaultFileExtension = ".png";
            savePicker.FileTypeChoices.Add(".png", new List<string> { ".png" });
            savePicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
            savePicker.SuggestedFileName = "snapshot.png";

            // Prompt the user to select a file
            var saveFile = await savePicker.PickSaveFileAsync();

            // Verify the user selected a file
            if (saveFile == null)
                return;

            // Encode the image to the selected file on disk
            using (var fileStream = await saveFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
            {
                var encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.PngEncoderId, fileStream);

                encoder.SetPixelData(
                    BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8,
                    BitmapAlphaMode.Ignore,
                    (uint)renderTargetBitmap.PixelWidth,
                    (uint)renderTargetBitmap.PixelHeight,
                    DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView().LogicalDpi,
                    DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView().LogicalDpi,
                    pixelBuffer.ToArray());

                await encoder.FlushAsync();
            }
```

This code is saving my image file onto my disk I want to change this code to share this image from my app not save on my disk ,How can I achieve that ? 
Need help.

Comment: The advice I have for you is to read this article: http://www.jeffblankenburg.com/2012/11/07/31-days-of-windows-8-day-7-share-contract